# Java date timezone to GMT and convert to another format

Tags: java, timezone, java.util.date

I have a list of `dates`. Example:

```
Tue Oct 21 17:05:37 EDT 2014
Tue Oct 22 18:05:37 IST 2014
Tue Oct 23 19:05:37 EST 2014
```

Since all dates are in dfferent timezone, i want to convert all dates to `GMT` zone and then convert all dates to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` format. ie, like this `2014-10-21T17:05:37` .

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your input strings are faulty. The 21st, 22nd, and 23rd cannot all be Tuesday. Please put more effort into writing your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

Define the dates you have in String variables like this:

```
String date1 = "Tue Oct 21 17:05:37 EDT 2014";
String date2 = "Wed Oct 22 18:05:37 IST 2014";
String date3 = "Thu Oct 23 19:05:37 EST 2014";
```

Create the representation of the current format that your dates are in:

```
SimpleDateFormat currentSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat wantedSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

And finally parse and format the dates:

```
System.out.println(wantedSDF.format(currentSDF.parse(date1)));
System.out.println(wantedSDF.format(currentSDF.parse(date2)));
System.out.println(wantedSDF.format(currentSDF.parse(date3)));
```

You may check all the availiable symbols for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Suggesting their use in 2020 is poor advice.

Comment: Well it was 2015 when I replied and not everybody was using Java 8 at that time..

Comment: Thus my use of the word “now”. My comment is not a criticism, it is a note to the future readers.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

Use modern *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome legacy classes seen in the other Answer.  Specifically, the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

By the way, those input string formats are terrible. Especially the use of `EDT`, `IST`, and such. Those are not true time zones. [These](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are real time zone names. Those pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique! So the `ZonedDateTime` class will take a guess as to what you might mean, but the results may be other than you intended. For example, is `IST` Irish Standard Time or India Standard Time?

Instead, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values as text.

I fixed your faulty input strings (Tuesday = 21, 22, and 23?).

```
List < String > inputs = List.of(
        "Tue Oct 21 17:05:37 EDT 2014" ,
        "Wed Oct 22 18:05:37 IST 2014" ,
        "Thu Oct 23 19:05:37 EST 2014"
);
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
```

Loop the inputs, attempting to parse each. Again, no guarantee as to the right time zone being guessed for your pseudo-zones.

```
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
    System.out.println( "zdt.toString() = " + zdt );
}
```

When run.

> zdt.toString() = 2014-10-21T17:05:37-04:00[America/New_York]
>
> zdt.toString() = 2014-10-22T18:05:37Z[Atlantic/Reykjavik]
>
> zdt.toString() = 2014-10-23T19:05:37-04:00[America/New_York]

[image]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).